# Selection box disappeared on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: gnome, files, drag-and-drop

When I use my mouse to select multiple items on `Files`, I see no drag-box.

But, I see an orange drag-box on my desktop when I do the same (which I would like to change to blue, but that's another thing).

How can I make my drag-box appear on `Files`?

Comment: switch to grid view instead https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/49348, and for colors there should be gnome colors or somethin package

Comment: didn't work. Also, `gnome color chooser` doesn't seem to be affective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because the `Nautilus Flowbox View` was enabled. To disable it open a terminal and execute the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences use-experimental-views false
```

Of course, you can use the `dconf-Editor` as well and follow the path above to toggle the setting.